# scala for yield setting a value

Tags: swing, scala, yield-keyword

I want to create a list of `GridBagPanel.Constraints`.
I read it in the scala programming book, that there is a cool `for-yield` construction, but I probably haven't understood the way it works correctly, because my code doesn't compile. Here it is:

```
        val d = for {
            i <- 0 until 4
            j <- 0 until 4
        } yield {
            c = new Constraints
            c.gridx = j
            c.gridy = i
        }
```

I want to generate a `List[Constraints]` and for every constraint set different x,y values so later, when I later add the components, they're going to be in a grid.

Comment: All you really need is to put a plain old `c` as the last expression in the yield block. In Scala, assignments have type Unit (vaguely `void`-ish) and every block has a value which is that of the last expression executed within it.

Comment: You should mark Daniel's answer as correct, not mine.  As he rightly points out for 2.7 it contains an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to return `c` at the end of the `yield` block to get a collection of `Constraints`. To get it to return a `List`, use a `List` instead of a `Range`. Like this:

```
val d = for {
            i <- List.range(0, 4)
            j <- List.range(0, 4)
        } yield {
            c = new Constraints
            c.gridx = j
            c.gridy = i
            c
        }
```

In fact, the original code would not do what you expected it to in Scala 2.7 because, there, ranges (as in `Range`) are non-strict. You may look it up on Stack Overflow or Google, but the short of it is that each time you looked up an element on `d`, it would create a new `Constraint`. This behavior has changed for Scala 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def conCreate = { 
    val c = new Constraints
    c.gridx = j
    c.gridy = i
    c
}

val d = for( i <- 0 until 4;
             j <- 0 until 4 ) yield conCreate(i,j)
```

I've replaced your call with a call to a function.  I had replaced until with Iterator.range(0,4) but I've returned it to until.  Both are valid code and actually mean the same thing.

Comment: Do you find `Iterator.range(0, 4)` more readable than `0 until 4`?

Comment: I've been writing something on Scala Iterators and Python itertools.  until is more concise.

Comment: That will not return a `List`, and, furthermore, it does unexpected things on Scala 2.7 because `Range` is non-strict there.

Comment: Nice post on your blog explaining the old way of 2.7: http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/10/strict-ranges.html  Very interesting and I must admit, I fell into this trap here.